# AES decryption issue using aes-128-ecb

Tags: node.js, aes

I'm trying to decrypt some data using aes-128-cbc using node.js. When I do same decryption using an online tool it works fine but somehow my node.js code has some bug which I'm unable to pinpoint , the result of decryption is not valid.

Below is working screenshot from an online tool . It works fine

[image]

Here is my code which has some issue

'''

```
var encData = '2WSGjqFJJ0Zxl7Ao6uT9+CpESHBPz+ejTlzPN+ELPtdFbL2cr3hJo/NM2XJXt1UKefdyJFjPxz//suRHM7PyorNtoVAoP8hdbcUndUtFEOpUihzVcllffRI3aoQ57iD5+5NZQEAncDwY/+fve/ocOCgBGJMRGN6CvjSJ9dIKFD2L0u452oBoMFBdkdNEslFabXFTxBut95BO1H+itJjOFCb9pQh0mK9HetzmUMjX7PZ55LysZRvddAracs7Fj3Jc';

var buf = Buffer.from(encData);
var encDataBase64 = buf.toString('base64');
var key = '6bhgdu99954paut6'; //dummy key for stackoverflow question 
var mykeydec = crypto.createDecipher('aes-128-ecb', key);
mykeydec.setAutoPadding(false);
var mystrdec = mykeydec.update(encDataBase64, 'base64', 'ascii');
mystrdec += mykeydec.final("ascii"); //?
console.log("dec data", mystrdec);
```

'''

Comment: What is the result of the decryption? Can you provide a runable example of your problem?

Answer (score 3):

The NodeJS-code has several issues: First, [`createDecipher`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createdecipher_algorithm_password_options) is used instead of [`createDecipheriv`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createdecipheriv_algorithm_key_iv_options). `createDecipher` (meanwhile deprecated by the way) interprets the 2nd parameter as passphrase and generates a key from it, while `CreateDecipheriv` interprets the 2nd parameter directly as key.

Second, when creating the buffer `buf`, an encoding must be used (here `base64`). However, this step can be omitted since the [`update`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_cipher_update_data_inputencoding_outputencoding)-method can also process a string (here the second parameter specifies the input-encoding).

Finally, PKCS7-[padding](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_cipher_setautopadding_autopadding) was used to encrypt the data, which is the default padding, so it must not be disabled for decryption.

With the following changes the ciphertext can be decrypted:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var encData = '2WSGjqFJJ0Zxl7Ao6uT9+CpESHBPz+ejTlzPN+ELPtdFbL2cr3hJo/NM2XJXt1UKefdyJFjPxz//suRHM7PyorNtoVAoP8hdbcUndUtFEOpUihzVcllffRI3aoQ57iD5+5NZQEAncDwY/+fve/ocOCgBGJMRGN6CvjSJ9dIKFD2L0u452oBoMFBdkdNEslFabXFTxBut95BO1H+itJjOFCb9pQh0mK9HetzmUMjX7PZ55LysZRvddAracs7Fj3Jc';

//var buf = Buffer.from(encData);
//var encDataBase64 = buf.toString('base64');
var key = '<your obfuscated secret key>'; 
//var mykeydec = crypto.createDecipher('aes-128-ecb', key);              // Use createDecipheriv
var mykeydec = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-ecb', key, null);
//mykeydec.setAutoPadding(false);                                        // Don't disable PKCS7-Padding                                        
//var mystrdec = mykeydec.update(encDataBase64, 'base64', 'ascii');      // Decrypt the Base64-encoded ciphertext directly
var mystrdec = mykeydec.update(encData, 'base64', 'ascii');
mystrdec += mykeydec.final("ascii"); 
console.log("dec data", mystrdec);
```

*In addition:* You have revealed so much information in your question that I was able to find your obfuscated key in a few minutes, which is why I was able to decrypt your ciphertext and hence verify my code changes. In other words, this key is compromised and must not be used anymore!

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure what your exact issue is. It could be a lot of things.
How is the data encrypted? Is the length of the string a multiple of the block size?

It could be that padding is needed if that is not the case.

In this example, it all works fine:

```
const crypto = require("crypto");

//Encrypt
const data = "{\"msg\":\"This data should be protected at all cost! But it is pretty long, so you need to use all chunks...\"}";
const key = "SecretKeyOfExactlyAndOnly32Bytes";
const chunks = [];
const encoder = crypto.createCipher("aes-128-ecb", Buffer.from(key));
encoder.setAutoPadding(true); // This does not match the block size, so padding is needed...
chunks.push(encoder.update(data).toString("base64"));
chunks.push(encoder.final().toString("base64"));
let cipherText = chunks.join("");
console.log("\nCiphertext: ", cipherText,"\n");

//Decrypt
let decoder = crypto.createDecipher("aes-128-ecb", key);
decoder.setAutoPadding(true); // setting this to false yields garbage data on the end because of padding...
let clearText = decoder.update(cipherText, "base64", "ascii");
clearText += decoder.final().toString("ascii");
console.log("\nClear Text: ", clearText);

//Verify Valid JSON
console.log(JSON.parse(clearText).msg);
```